# Plugin dependency on an internal module

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection, maven-plugin

I have many modules in my project and let's say two of them are module A and module B. I have specified a dependency on the JAR of module A under the plugin tag of the pom for module B.

```
POM for module B:
<plugin>
 ............
 ............
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>module-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The issue I am facing is that before the build begins i.e. before the JAR for module A is created, pom for module B is getting scanned and I am getting error that says:

```
"The POM for module A is missing, no dependency information available"
```

I do not have access to an online repository where I can host JAR for module A. How can I go about doing this locally? How do I ensure that JAR for module A is present locally before this scan takes place?

Comment: Is this dependency a dependency of a plugin? Do you build that plugin as well? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Maven determines the correct build order automatically.

I do not know whether plugin dependencies are accounted for as well.

In case of doubt I would move `module-A` before `module-B` in the list of modules in the main POM.

Comment: Unfortunately plugin dependencies are not correctly detected during reactor scan, so the only way is to manually install modules from dependency part to local repo

Comment: @mario45211 No, you can just move `module-A` before `module-B` in your reactor POM. See my answer.

Comment: Okay, but it's not work for my project. I believed reactor scan should detect plugin dependency on another module from project, but instead maven is trying to find my parent module in repository...

Comment: @mario45211 Then you should probably ask a question here on SO with the details.